# Thinning for the mcmc function in coda in R

Tags: r, markov-chains, mcmc

I am a little confused about the documentation of coda for declaring an mcmc object given the data.

It says (from [documentation on page 21](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/coda.pdf)):
"Likewise, if data represents a chain that has already been thinned, the thinning interval should be given as the thin argument."

Currently, my data set that I plan to input to this function already has the samples discarded out due to thinning. In other words, if my original MCMC chain is: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6, and my thinning interval is 2, then the data that I plan to feed to mcmc function in coda is just 0,2,4,6.

Is this what the documentation means by a chain that has already been "thinned"? If so, why do I need to specify thin = 2?

In other words, I am debating if I should call the function like this, assuming that data = c(0,2,4,6):
mcmc(data,thin = 1) or mcmc(data, thin = 2)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `mcmc(data, thin = 2)` where data = c(0,2,4,6).

You'll see this if you `plot(mcmc(data, thin = 2))` and `plot(mcmc(data, thin = 1)`. In the thin = 1 case, the plot would show less number of iterations in the plot.

Comment: Thanks so much for the very helpful response! I'm new to coda and want to make sure my results are correct.